# Asp.Net Core Authorization with Google

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I am attempting to get an access token to use with google's gmail apis. I was hoping to use the built in asp.net core authentication for this.
I want to use the authorization code flow.

In my first application I was getting the google authorization code from redirecting to the google token endpoint in my javascript code when the user clicked on a button:

```
function getCode(){
    
    let uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
    uri += "?";
    uri += "";
    uri += "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth";
    uri += "&scope=https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    uri += "&response_type=code";
    uri += "&response_mode=form_post";
    uri += "&state=qu7kti2m4ar";
    window.location.href = uri;
}
```

Then the user would be presented with the consent screen to authorize my app to their gmail.

At which point I instructed google to redirect them to my "/auth" endpoint. Which I have a controller method waiting for google to respond here:

```
        [Route("/auth")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AuthAsync()
        {
            string token = _adapter.GetSaveTokenAsync(Request).Result;
            await _adapter.LoginUser(token);
            return View("_Auth");
        }
```

The GetSaveTokenAsync reads the token from the Request body.
The LoginUser method makes a call to the google token endpoint with my secret and the code, to get an access token, which I can use on the google apis to get the users infromation.

I am attempting to implement this with the Asp.Net authentication so that it handles things like settings cookies, antiforgery, saving the user to local db, etc.

I followed along with this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

This is where I set up the service in my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = configuration["googleClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = configuration["googleClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = "/auth";
    options.Scope.Add("https://mail.google.com/");
});
```

It is effectively logging in the user when I click the login button. But my endpoint is not getting hit on the redirect - the /auth

Here is my controller:

```
[Route("/auth")]
public IActionResult Auth()
{
    Console.WriteLine("made it to auth");
    return View();
}
```

When I make a request to this endpoint directly in my browser (localhost:5001/auth) I get:
Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.

Mapping the controllers here:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
```

I notice when I click the login, my consent screen doesn't open up asking to allow my app to read, edit, etc. my gmail files. Which is what my app is set up to do.

I am a little confused on what the Google Authentication in Asp.Net core is doing. Why is it just logging in and routing to my index method. It looks like this is just for signing in, but it doesn't look like it is using OpenId. Doesn't seem like the authorization code flow is being used and that this is almost like a client credential flow. Is the authorization code flow possible with asp.net core identity/ authorization?

There is a post here that seems related refereing to using the Identity Server Nuget Package but when I click the links I get 404s. I went to the Nuget Package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4, went to the github, and the documentation links there are also giving me 404s.

Comment: It took me over a year to truly grok OIDC. If you really want to understand what's going on I recommend ignoring everything Google-specific and [start-off with the OAuth2 RFCs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749), then moving on to [the official OIDC documentation](https://openid.net/developers/how-connect-works/), and only _then_ looking at Google's extensions to OIDC. Good luck.

Comment: Can you access your `Auth` method if you hit `http://localhost:8080/auth` in your browser?

Comment: _"ASP.NET Identity"_ and _IdentityServer_ are entirely separate things with entirely orthogonal responsibilities - but in-short, ASP.NET Identity is basically a quickstart-kit to quickly get a (secure) user login and management system working (including database, pw resets, etc) - while IdentityServer (now called [Duende IdentityServer](https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver)) is basically a package that does about 80% of the work required to build your own OIDC Server (you still need to do your own UI/UX, database, etc). You can use ASP.NET Identity with IdentityServer as well.

Comment: @Orifjon, good point. I edited the post to include that now. I am getting this exception: Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid. I also notice the asp.net core defines the callback path as this: "The request path within the application's base path where the user-agent will be returned. The middleware will process this request when it arrives." So it seems like the middleware is processing the redirect. Is there a way to hook my code into this to retrieve the authorization code?

Comment: @Dai So it sounds like Asp.Net Identity is not what I want for creating an OAuth flow in my project? I have no problem creating it myself, but if Asp.Net had a built-in way of doing so I was hoping to utilize it. Thanks for the link to the Identity Server, but this isn't serious enough for a license

Comment: @JamesCampbell If you just want your website/webapp/webservice to use Google as an IdP then you don't need ASP.NET Identity _nor_ IdentityServer, just use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` NuGet package and follow the instructions in [the article that you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0).